# Creating a column in data.frame counting the number of columns that satisfies certain condition

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I have a data.frame `df` with columns `col1, col2... col25` and `Threshold`.

I would like to create a new column A that records, for each row, the number of columns in col1... col25 that have values above Threshold.

I think I can do

```
df$A <- (df[paste("col",1,sep="")] >= df["Threshold"]) + (df[paste("col",2,sep="")] >= df["Threshold"]) + ...
```

but it's not very elegant, which makes me think there must be a nicer and more compact way.

(NB: I need the columns name to be recomposed from strings, the real columns names are PV1MATH, PV2MATH, PV1SCIE, etc.)

EDIT: to generate the data

```
colnames <- paste("PV", rep(1:2, 5), c("MATH", "SCIE", "ENGI", "PHYS", "ARTS"), sep="")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200, 60, 20), ncol=10))
names(df) <- colnames
df$Threshold <- rpois(20, 50)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generated some random data so that an example can be provided:

```
> colnames <- paste("PV", rep(1:2, 5), c("MATH", "SCIE", "ENGI", "PHYS", "ARTS"), sep="")
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200, 60, 20), ncol=10))
> names(df) <- colnames
> df$Threshold <- rpois(20, 50)
> head(df)
   PV1MATH   PV2SCIE  PV1ENGI  PV2PHYS   PV1ARTS   PV2MATH   PV1SCIE  PV2ENGI  PV1PHYS  PV2ARTS Threshold
1 65.38862  59.10253 36.58240 54.32805  9.181924  55.01604 73.377464 75.57304 60.93116 31.99255        49
2 46.58772  81.16455 70.60132 19.45667 93.797606  12.80517 47.920166 51.90083 41.72037 63.98710        50
3 67.02016  57.85148 64.67905 24.49892 48.827826  57.26432 53.117871 67.83863 57.56008 67.69975        41
4 61.36172 107.93095 70.78672 38.21072 75.752956  48.12871 40.698131 82.58197 60.66945 61.52466        51
5 19.54413  51.27288 52.15215 71.99829 64.433654 116.80112 47.297671 57.39038 97.73618 75.57284        50
6 68.37724  40.35299 74.26690 60.44868 60.037653  40.99726  6.843594 84.68163 65.08556 62.26077        45
> 
> df$Above.Threshold <- rowSums(df[, -grep("Threshold", names(df))] > df$Threshold)
> head(df)
   PV1MATH   PV2SCIE  PV1ENGI  PV2PHYS   PV1ARTS   PV2MATH   PV1SCIE  PV2ENGI  PV1PHYS  PV2ARTS Threshold Above.Threshold
1 65.38862  59.10253 36.58240 54.32805  9.181924  55.01604 73.377464 75.57304 60.93116 31.99255        49               7
2 46.58772  81.16455 70.60132 19.45667 93.797606  12.80517 47.920166 51.90083 41.72037 63.98710        50               5
3 67.02016  57.85148 64.67905 24.49892 48.827826  57.26432 53.117871 67.83863 57.56008 67.69975        41               9
4 61.36172 107.93095 70.78672 38.21072 75.752956  48.12871 40.698131 82.58197 60.66945 61.52466        51               7
5 19.54413  51.27288 52.15215 71.99829 64.433654 116.80112 47.297671 57.39038 97.73618 75.57284        50               8
6 68.37724  40.35299 74.26690 60.44868 60.037653  40.99726  6.843594 84.68163 65.08556 62.26077        45               7
```

In your case you can simply use the liner

```
df$Above.Threshold <- rowSums(df[, -grep("Threshold", names(df))] > df$Threshold)
```

assuming that the data is a `data.frame` with name `df`.

Alternatively, if you want to select on which columns the above-threshold-sum is computed, you can change the `grep` condition. For example,select the columns that have prefix `PV`:

```
> df$Above.Threshold <- rowSums(df[, grep("^PV", names(df))] > df$Threshold)
# same results
> head(df)
   PV1MATH   PV2SCIE  PV1ENGI  PV2PHYS   PV1ARTS   PV2MATH   PV1SCIE  PV2ENGI  PV1PHYS  PV2ARTS Threshold Above.Threshold
1 65.38862  59.10253 36.58240 54.32805  9.181924  55.01604 73.377464 75.57304 60.93116 31.99255        49               7
2 46.58772  81.16455 70.60132 19.45667 93.797606  12.80517 47.920166 51.90083 41.72037 63.98710        50               5
3 67.02016  57.85148 64.67905 24.49892 48.827826  57.26432 53.117871 67.83863 57.56008 67.69975        41               9
4 61.36172 107.93095 70.78672 38.21072 75.752956  48.12871 40.698131 82.58197 60.66945 61.52466        51               7
5 19.54413  51.27288 52.15215 71.99829 64.433654 116.80112 47.297671 57.39038 97.73618 75.57284        50               8
6 68.37724  40.35299 74.26690 60.44868 60.037653  40.99726  6.843594 84.68163 65.08556 62.26077        45               7
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I ensure that the summation is only done over the "PV" columns, but not over other numeric columns, eg `age`?

Comment: In that case, change `-grep("Threshold")` to `grep("^PV")`, it will select those columns with prefix `"PV"`.