# Counting (for each row) how many times an OR condition on several columns is satisfied

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, conditional-statements

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247121/creating-a-column-in-data-frame-counting-the-number-of-columns-that-satisfies-ce), except a bit different. In the initial question, I was trying to count (for each row) how many columns satisfied a condition. I would like to do something similar, except that the condition involves several columns with an OR condition, and my real data has many columns, so ideally, I'd like to reference the columns using a regular expression.

I have the following data:

```
colnames <- c(paste("col",rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=4),rep(1:4,2),sep=""),c("meh","muh"))
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("Yes","No"),200,replace=TRUE),ncol=10))
names(df) <- colnames
df
   colA1 colA2 colA3 colA4 colB1 colB2 colB3 colB4 meh muh
1     No   Yes    No    No    No   Yes   Yes    No Yes Yes
2     No   Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes    No   Yes    No  No  No
3     No    No    No   Yes    No    No    No    No Yes  No
4    Yes    No   Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes   Yes  No Yes
5    Yes    No   Yes    No    No    No    No   Yes  No Yes
6    Yes    No    No    No   Yes   Yes    No    No  No  No
7    Yes    No    No    No   Yes   Yes   Yes    No Yes  No
8    Yes    No   Yes    No   Yes   Yes    No   Yes Yes  No
9     No   Yes    No    No    No   Yes   Yes    No  No  No
10   Yes   Yes    No    No   Yes    No   Yes    No Yes  No
11    No   Yes    No    No   Yes    No   Yes   Yes  No  No
12    No   Yes   Yes   Yes    No    No   Yes    No  No  No
13    No    No   Yes   Yes    No   Yes   Yes   Yes Yes  No
14   Yes   Yes    No    No    No    No   Yes    No  No Yes
15   Yes    No   Yes   Yes    No   Yes    No   Yes  No  No
16    No   Yes   Yes    No    No    No   Yes    No  No  No
17   Yes    No    No    No    No   Yes   Yes   Yes  No Yes
18   Yes    No   Yes   Yes    No    No    No    No  No Yes
19    No    No    No    No    No   Yes    No    No  No Yes
20    No   Yes    No    No   Yes   Yes   Yes    No  No  No
```

I would like to create a new column `Nb` that records, for each line: the number of times at least one of colA2, colA3,colA4 is =="Yes" plus the number of times at least one of colB2, colB3,colB4 is =="Yes".

If there was not this "OR" condition implied when look at a group of columns [colA2, colA3,colA4], and I was adding the number of columns satisfying the condition, I could have used something like:

```
df$Nb <- rowSums(df[, grep("^col[A-B][2-4]", names(df))] == "Yes")
```

I would like to use regex if possible to reference the columns, as in my real data letters and numbers go further than B and 5 respectively.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you just change the variables within the `grep`?  `grep('^col[A-N][2-30], names(df))`?

Comment: You should really transform those "Yes"/"No" values into logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`).

Comment: @maloneypatr I could, but the expression I wrote would not accomplish what I want; instead, it would simply count the number of columns that are == "Yes".

Comment: @Roland That's a good idea. I am doing it using `df[, grep("^col[A-B][2-4]", names(df))] <- (df[, grep("^col[A-B][2-4]", names(df))] == "Yes")`. Is that efficient (enough)?

Comment: @Peutch Yes, that's efficient. But why don't you do it with all columns?

Comment: @Roland The datasets have been collected with "Yes", "No" type of answers. I have reasonably big datasets, so I only want to manipulate the data that I need. I do not need colA1, colB1, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could adapt your `rowSums` approach to just the groups of columns in each of your OR conditions, then add `> 0` to make it "at least one." Thus, "at least one of the A values is Yes" would look like:

```
rowSums(df[, grep("^colA[2-4]", names(df))] == "Yes") > 0
```

Then you can combine them using `+`:

```
(rowSums(df[, grep("^colA[2-4]", names(df))] == "Yes") > 0) +
 (rowSums(df[, grep("^colB[2-4]", names(df))] == "Yes") > 0)
```

---

Incidentally, you would have an easier time answering questions like these if your data were in a [tidy format](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf): that is, if each column were a separate variable. Right now it looks like you're storing attributes of your data (A, B, 1-4) as parts of your column names, which is the reason operations like "using columns with the value 'A'" are very awkward. What if you instead rearranged your data, using the dplyr and tidyr packages, as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df$index <- 1:nrow(df)
newdf <- df %>% gather(key, value, colA1:colB4) %>%
    separate(key, c("col", "letter", "number"), c(-3, -2)) %>%
    mutate(number = as.numeric(number))
```

This rearranges your data as (note that I gave each of your rows its own "index" variable):

```
  meh muh index col letter number value
1 Yes  No     1 col      A      1   Yes
2 Yes  No     2 col      A      1   Yes
3  No  No     3 col      A      1   Yes
4 Yes  No     4 col      A      1    No
5 Yes Yes     5 col      A      1    No
6 Yes Yes     6 col      A      1   Yes
```

You can then group, summarize, filter and manipulate these observations more naturally. For example, you seem to want to drop the columns with the number 1: rather than needing a regular expression, you could simply do `newdf %>% filter(number > 1)`.

Here's how you would perform the kind of OR operation you're describing:

```
hasyes <- newdf %>% group_by(index, letter) %>% filter(number > 1) %>%
              summarize(hasyes = any(value == "Yes"))
```

For each of your original row+letter combinations, you now have a logical value for whether `Yes` appears:

```
  index letter hasyes
1     1      A   TRUE
2     1      B   TRUE
3     2      A   TRUE
4     2      B   TRUE
5     3      A  FALSE
6     3      B   TRUE
```

One more summarizing operation gets this into the form you want:

```
result <- hasyes %>% group_by(index) %>% summarize(yeses = sum(hasyes))
```

What's important about this solution is that it will work for *any number of letters you have* (that is, if it goes from A-Z instead of just A and B) equally easily.

Comment: Thank you, that's a clever approach. Do you if there'd be any way for me not to have to specify a term of the sum for each letter A, B... In my real data, letters go quite far, so it'd be a bit annoying to write a term in the sum for each.