# R Generating a new variable based on conditional statement applied to many columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, lapply

There is probably an obvious and elegant way to do this, probably using lapply, but I am still mastering  apply commands and am struggling to find it.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following except that instead of 5 factor variables there are dozens and instead of 10 rows there are hundreds.

```
    a<- data.frame("id" = c(1:10),
                   "a1" = factor(c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)),
                   "a2" = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)), 
                   "a3" = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)),
                   "a4" = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)), 
                   "a5" = factor(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

I want to create a new variable which is 1 if any of 13 columns contain a particular level of the factor.  The equivalent in the example dataframe would be creating a new variable called "b" which is 1 is there's a "1" in any of the columns a1:a4, which would look like the following.

```
    a<- data.frame("id" = c(1:10),
                   "a1" = factor(c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)),
                   "a2" = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)), 
                   "a3" = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)),
                   "a4" = factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)), 
                   "a5" = factor(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)), 
                   "b"  = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1))
```

There has GOT to be a way to do this using the 13 column positions instead of writing a conditional ifthen statement for each of the 13 variables.

Comment: This is clear that you need to reshape your data such that it has a column for "variable", which is then a factor containing "a1", "a2", "a3"... and a column for value, that contains all the 0s and 1s. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26042270/712603) for an explanation of why this makes this kind of problem much easier.

Comment: Thanks.  The link's very helpful.  Identifying columns using regular expressions worked nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `rowSums`, something like this:

```
> as.numeric(rowSums(a[paste0("a", 1:5)] == 1) >= 1)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: (I see now that David's comment includes a link that takes a very similar approach...)

Comment: I'm getting a "undefined columns selected" error.  Further thoughts?

Comment: @user2230555, sure. You're trying to select columns that don't exist in your dataset.

Comment: Or even `(rowSums(a[-1] == 1) > 0)+0`

Answer (score 0):

In case you wanted to try `lapply`

```
  Reduce(`|`,lapply(a[,-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))+0
  #[1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Or just

```
  Reduce(`|`, lapply(a[,-1], `==`, 1)) +0
  #[1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(155)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 5000*1e4, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000))

library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function() {as.numeric(rowSums(df == 1) >= 1) }
f2 <- function() {Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `==`, 1)) +0}
f3 <- function() {apply(df == 1, 1, function(x) any(x %in% TRUE))+0}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative")
# Unit: relative
# expr       min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# f1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
# f2() 1.040561 1.043713 1.053773 1.032932 1.045067   100
# f3() 2.538287 2.517184 2.825253 2.477225 2.454511   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `any` after converting the matrix to logical.

```
> apply(a[grep("a[1-4]", names(a))] == 1, 1, any)+0
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

Or

```
> apply(a[grepl("a[1-4]", names(a))] == 1, 1, any)+0
# [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```